# how to save date and time using localtime in Django?

Tags: django, python-2.7

So I am trying to learn Python and Django... Great language and framework.

That said, please excuse me for my seemingly very dumb question.

I have a Django project which won't be used outside a single timezone, so it doesn't really make much sense to save stuff in UTC and convert to the "local" timezone when needed.

The problem is that I can't seem to find a "Python/Django" way to do it properly as seen below:

```
> python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 19, 10, 17, 58, 153065, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo     'America/Sao_Paulo' BRST-1 day, 22:00:00 DST>)
>>> from thingie.models import Thingie
>>>  a=Thingie(field1="teste",field2="12121",field3="112121",field4="904095034",timestamp=timezone.localtime(timezone.now()))
>>> a.save()
```

As it stands, this creates a record in my MySQL database, but the timestamp field is recorded as UTC time...

What am I doing wrong?  How can I save the timestamp in localtime?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

As per my comments to Daniel's response, using datetime generates a warning in Django, which led me to disable USE_TZ (`USE_TZ = False`).  This seemed to do the trick, but I wonder if there are any unwanted behaviours, since the documentation recommends to use timezone support.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about timezones, don't do anything at all; just save it.

```
a = Thingie(field1="teste", field2="12121", field3="112121", field4="904095034", timestamp=datetime.datetime.now()))
```

Note, for timestamps, it's simpler to use the `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` options in the field definition, which will set the time automatically.

Comment: `>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 19, 10, 31, 35, 808237)
>>> a=Nfe(xml="teste",chave_de_acesso="12121",numero_nota="112121",nsu="904095034",timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
>>> a.save()
/Users/paulolindoso/Envs/transporte_teste/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1474: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Nfe.timestamp received a naive datetime (2015-10-19 10:31:58.511284) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)`